# Why does Lubuntu not allow me to run the Virtual Box Guest Additions?

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, virtualization, executable, guest-additions

On most up-to-date Ubuntu flavours that I install in VMs in Virtual Box when I choose the option to `Insert Guest Additions CD image...` I am shortly asked if I wish to run what is one there, and when I choose to do so a Terminal windows opens up which installs it.
However on Lubuntu this is not the case, it just asks me if I would like to open it with the file manager, and then even though there are executable files in there, executing them doesn't seem to do much good, so how do I install it on Lubuntu and why doesn't it just act like the rest of the Ubuntu flavours and offer to immediately run it for me?

I have tried this in both Lubuntu 14.04.4 LTS and 15.10 (though I currently have 15.10 in the VM). And I am running the latest version of Virtual Box.

Comment: Just install it from repo or  manualy from terminal? http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm

Comment: In Lubuntu you also need to install the gcc compiler (see [note 3](http://askubuntu.com/a/22745/3940)) and make uilts (all also come with build-essentials).

Comment: @Takkat: Why aren't they installed by default?

Comment: @Takkat: Well, if that will fix the problem so that it behaves like the other flavours, then please post this as an answer.

Comment: @Takkat: Well, you can't be sure it's a dupe because I haven't actually tried it yet...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Oracle documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp46457697871104) gives a reasonable 'manual' method to install the Guest Additions which should fit in with your problem.

First update and then install dkms:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Then when on your system the Guest Additions option opens a File Manager window: open a Terminal window *in that location* and run:

```
sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

If you successfully mount the Guest Additions iso but get no window at all you should still be able to find the iso mounted in `/media/$USER/VBOXADDITIONS_version`. So currently on my system the mount point is:

```
/media/andrew/VBOXADDITIONS_5.0.8_103449
```

Of course this will vary according to which version of the Guest Additions you are actually using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer by the way! It has been a great help to me in many situations now! :)

Comment: Great to hear :)

Comment: for Lubuntu 17.04 @AlikElzin-kilaka 's solution works: https://askubuntu.com/questions/533071/virtualbox-4-12-shared-clipboard-not-working-in-ubuntu14-04?noredirect=1&lq=1

sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
enable bi-directionnal clipboard
sudo reboot