# VirtualBox 5.2.4 Shared clipboard not working in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: virtualbox, clipboard

I have tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms and enabling bidirectional shared clipboard.
```

[VirtualBox 4.12 Shared clipboard not working in Ubuntu14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533071/virtualbox-4-12-shared-clipboard-not-working-in-ubuntu14-04)

and various other things, now hard to collect, but nothing works so far.

How to fix it?

**Update**

When trying to insert guest additions CD image, I get this error:

[image: could not mount error]

From this question, [Unable to Install Guest Additions CD Image on Virtual Box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573596/unable-to-install-guest-additions-cd-image-on-virtual-box), I tried:

[image: installing virtualbox-guest-utils]

Tried also:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso and this gives:
```

[image: already the newest version]

Restarting the virtual machine did not help, no errors.

Comment: "Started working..." I am confused. I don't see this in the link you shared. Did you get this working or not?

Comment: @Buck - oh, I have made mistake by copying. It is still not working, edited post.

Comment: did you install the guest-additions into the guest OS?

Comment: this one: sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms ? I think I did

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VirtualBox 4.12 Shared clipboard not working in Ubuntu14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533071/virtualbox-4-12-shared-clipboard-not-working-in-ubuntu14-04)

Comment: are you downgrading your VirtualBox from V6.1.4 to V6.1.2, then you solved this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`virtualbox-guest-dkms`'s version in Ubuntu 16.04.3 is `5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2`, which is the version of VirtualBox in Ubuntu's repository rather than 5.2.4. This might be causing your issue.

Try the following to install the proper version of Guest Additions:

1. Start the virtual machine
2. In the VirtualBox `Devices` menu, choose `Insert Guest Additions CD image...`
3. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
4. Run `sudo apt purge virtualbox-guest-dkms`
5. Run `sudo /media/$USER/VBox_GAs_5.2.4/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`
6. Reboot

Except for step 4, it's a good idea to do this every time there's a new version of VirtualBox (step 5 should be changed to the proper path, of course).

Comment: Inserting guess additions gives error, updated the post.

Comment: Fixed not being able to insert guest additions image by https://askubuntu.com/questions/573596/unable-to-install-guest-additions-cd-image-on-virtual-box Dave Rose answer. And now it works - thank you, you are genius! How do you know that? :) why I cannot find that information?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the "shared clipboard" bug in 6.1.4 while running on a Windows host.  I know that it is, indeed, a not-yet-unresolved bug in this version of VirtualBox.

As others have suggested, I found that I could bypass the problem by reinstalling version 6.1.2 of the Guest Additions.  I found the necessary Windows installer by going to "Older builds 6.0" on the VirtualBox website, then manually editing the URL from 6_0 to 6_1.

Then, after installing the Windows side of things (VirtualBox very graciously understands the idea of "downgrade"), you of course must then mount the CD image, and run the Linux-side `".run"` file as root. *(Exactly as you must do with any Guest Additions release ...)*  Then, *restart the VirtualBox application on the host,* and boot the virtual machine.  (You must thereby update the software on both sides.)

Of course this problem is actively being discussed on the VirtualBox web site and it is a known, confirmed problem. *("Zed, we have a bug!")* I'm quite sure that 6.1.5 will have a permanent solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19336) in 6.1.4 discussed in the [forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=97038). The solution is to download and install [VirtualBox Guest Additions 6.1.97 r136310](https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.97-136310.iso) as mentioned in [this comment](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19336#comment:33).
Or wait for the new release 6.1.5

Comment: Thank you!! This was driving me nuts. I uninstalled and installed 6.1.2 and now it works.

Comment: Thank you; installed [6.1.5](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19336#comment:40) testbuild GuestAdditions and it worked like a charm