# VirtualBox shared clipboard does not work

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, clipboard

I have on a Xubuntu 16.04 another Xubuntu 17 running in a VirtualBox. I have the `bidirectional clipboard share` activated and have also installed

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

on the guest. But even after rebooting I can't copy/paste between the guest and host machine.

I am running `Parcellite` on the host,could that be a problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should install `virtualbox-guest-x11` package as dkms installs only the  drivers. Then run the command `VBoxClient --clipboard`.

Sources [How to fix virtualbox's copy and paste to host-machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63420/how-to-fix-virtualboxs-copy-and-paste-to-host-machine)

Answer (score 3):

The method with 'VBoxClient --clipboard' did not work for me.

So, I **downgraded VirtualBox** from verison `6.1.4` to `6.1.2` and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

I did not get any response here and could not figure it out - tried many options (same problem with VMPlayer also).

But the good news, at least from cut-n-paste perspective, **use an alternative client**. You can use SSH to log into the machine using your favorite tool - PuTTY or even cmd will work. This actually is a better solution - no need to muck with mouse capture and all that.

1. So just setup an SSH server:

   ```
   $ sudo apt update
   $ sudo apt install openssh-server
   $ sudo systemctl status ssh
   Active: active (running)
   ```
2. Open firewall:

   ```
   sudo ufw allow ssh
   ```
3. Check IP address:

   ```
   ip a
   ```
4. SSH in with PuTTY or cmd or:

   ```
   ssh <username>@<ip_address>
   ```

You are done! It should work like a charm!

Note: This SSH works only from local host as the VM only has a private IP. If you can create a public IP on a VM (that is another arduous adventure - still working on it), you will be able to remote SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Using latest Virtual Box 6.1 on Windows10 host, using Ubuntu 18.04 guest

First I had installed by downloading [How To Install VirtualBox Guest Additions on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu/)

`sudo apt install build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

`sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run --nox11`

The install was successful, It should have worked but didn't

Next I did  (as suggested above):
 `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms`
`VBoxClient --clipboard`

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11`

This also did not work, I have rebooted and all that, enabled bidirectional - clipboard, drag-n-drop, etc.
Not only cut-n-paste does not work, I cant even scroll my mouse pointer above the prompt - so essentially makes the VM useless.
You would expect something like this to work by default, but unfortunately not, even after all the hoops.

Comment: If you use Ubuntu Sever you can not use clipboard, mouse integration. Only Shared Folders.

Comment: @ adasiko - I was not aware of this limitation, documentation etc are not clear about this.

Comment: The menu has enable clip board, drag drop etc - none of them work. I thought setting X11 etc would make it work. But total waste of time. (same with VM Player also)

Comment: As I "answered" above, I think that *Oracle* has a bug in their latest 6.1 release.  I also noticed that, after a completely-proper install of the necessary software on host and guest, the clipboard-sharing broke.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded my VirtualBox to 6.1, and the Guest Additions on my Ubuntu guest to the corresponding version, and right now *I think* that this introduced a bug because my clipboard-sharing also stopped working ... as soon as I upgraded.  *(Yes, I installed the Additions both on the host and on my Ubuntu guest.)*

Therefore, I'm pretty sure that this is **Oracle's** bug, and that we'll be seeing a hot-fix coming out from them in a few days.