# VirtualBox 6.1.4 - shared clipboard does not work Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I have:

- VirtualBox - 6.1.4 r136177 (Qt5.6.2)
- Host: Windows - 10
- Guest: Ubuntu Desktop - 18.04 LTS

About VirtualBox having

- `Sharedclipboard` and `Drag n Drop` configured with *bidirectional*
- `Extension Pack` 6.1.4 r136177 installed

And the `Guest` Ubuntu having:

- `Guest Additions` installed

The *Shared Clipboard* feature does not work how is expected.

- `Ctrl + C` + `Ctrl + V` between Host/Guest and vice versa, right?

Confirm that they are the correct combination.

Because I tried with

- `Shift + Ctrl[left|right] + c` - `Shift + Ctrl[left|right] + v`
- `Ctrl[left|right] + Shift + c` - `Ctrl[left|right] + Shift + v`

and does not work

What is missing?

I read these links:

- [Why doesn't clipboard sharing work with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS inside VirtualBox 5.1.26?](https://superuser.com/a/1367954)
- [VirtualBox shared clipboard does not work](https://askubuntu.com/a/978919)

Both do mention to install `virtualbox-guest-x11`

**Assumption**: of course, assuming it should enable in peace the shared clipboard feature.

Through the `sudo apt search virtualbox` command I got a list and I can see these two coincidences

```
virtualbox-guest-x11/bionic-updates 5.2.34-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64
  x86 virtualization solution - X11 guest utilities

virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe/bionic-updates 5.2.34-dfsg-0~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64
  x86 virtualization solution - X11 guest utilities
```

Working with the former, I tried but arises:

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-x11
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-guest-x11 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-23
                        Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18.99.901)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am not a Linux/Ubuntu expert, my **concern** is avoid to create conflicts with *VirtualBox - Guest Additions* and *virtualbox-guest-x11* mostly because their versions are not the same.

So I should go and install anyway that dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug in Virtualbox Guest Additions 6.1.4. Fixed in test builds. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds (VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.5-136807.iso for now)

Comment: I had this problem even with VB 5.x series, interesting, btw through your link or other, how do you know it is a bug? and mostly that the mentioned build fixed the bug?

Comment: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19336

Comment: I can confirm it works fine now since `6.1.6`