# Why Ubuntu Desktop 18 client to Windows 10 host clipboard doesn't work?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, virtualization, clipboard

**UPDATE:** after playing around, the issue is limited only to Chrome `81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and Chromium `81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) snap (64-bit)` (can paste text but can't copy text to the host). Working on Terminal, Files, Text Editor, Sublime Text,...

I'm a new Linux user, trying to find an alternative solution for my Windows desktop.

My issue: unable to use clipboard to copy from Ubuntu **guest** to Windows 10 **host**, while Windows 10 **host** to Ubuntu **guest** is working properly.

Below is my setup:

- Host: Windows 10. `winver` 1511 (OS build 10586.104)
- VM: VirtualBox 6.0.14 r133895 (Qt5.6.2) (I don't want to upgrade to newer version due to its [another clipboard bug](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=97038))
- Guests:

  - Windows 7, `winver` 6.1 (7601 SP1), all 4 Windows 7 boxes working flawlessly (clipboard host <--> guest)
  - Ubuntu 7 Desktop 18.04.4 LTS `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I have tried:

- Reboot
- Switch between VirtualBox clipboard sharing options
- Reinstall VirtualBox Guest Addition https://superuser.com/questions/1318231/why-doesnt-clipboard-sharing-work-with-ubuntu-18-04-lts-inside-virtualbox-5-1-2
- Install `virtualbox-guest-x11` but same error in [VirtualBox 6.1.4 - shared clipboard does not work Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223771/virtualbox-6-1-4-shared-clipboard-does-not-work-ubuntu-18-04)

I have tried all solutions I could find in 3 days but no luck.

Comment: Does this reference help answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/1318231/why-doesnt-clipboard-sharing-work-with-ubuntu-18-04-lts-inside-virtualbox-5-1-2

Comment: @Graham nope, it was one of my attempt but it was not working

Comment: "I don't want to upgrade to newer version due to its another clipboard bug (6.1.4)" - fixed in 6.1.6

Answer (score 0):

Based on suggestion [Why Ubuntu Desktop 18 client to Windows 10 host clipboard doesn't work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228477/why-ubuntu-desktop-18-client-to-windows-10-host-clipboard-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment2067390_1228477) I updated the VirtualBox to latest version 6.1.6 and it fixed the clipboard problem.